# Get a variable from a file to another file in node.js( problem not solve )

Tags: node.js

I tried too many time but I couldn't a get solution to my problem.
my file structure is like following:

---

- static
- views
- server.js
- package.json

In the static folder, there are two file 1.js and 2.js.I want to access a  variable from file 2.js from file 1.js .

Error come: require is not defined

Comment: how do you execute your script ?

Comment: first of all, I written code like this 

const favoriteAuthor = { name: "Ken Bruen", genre: "Noir", nationality: "Irish" };

module.exports.favoriteAuthor = favoriteAuthor;

and access these variable into 1.js using this code 
var data = require('./2')


error come continue 

for remove this error, I have to install another module

Comment: I meant are you using this command to run your script: `node 1` ?? or are you executing it in the browser

Comment: I tried command node server.js